# Counting events

Tags: d3.js, cubism.js

I'm using Cube and Cubism. It's perfect, except for one thing... I need to display the total events numerically. E.g. I have a metric showing API calls per 10 second, I need to know the total API calls.

Is there anything built-in that I'm missing?

I thought about adding a (Mongo) count in the evaluator, but events expire so that wouldn't work.

Keeping track of the running total client-side and including it in the event could be an option, but the sources are distributed and the events are not monotonic, so a simple sum on the last 10 seconds won't work. I would need to be able to query 'get the last event for each distinct source'. Is that possible?

I have a lot of metrics, so I really want to keep the number of client requests to a minimum. If I could get e.g. `cumulative` alongside `value` in the standard metric query I'd be happy.

EDIT

I was missing something... using `sum` and a large (e.g. 1 day) step works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing something... using sum and a large (e.g. 1 day) step works perfectly.